# Efficiently updating names of columns in dataframe in R with common name

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
d <- data.frame(
  sub = c(101, 102, 103),
  dmpfc = c(1,2,3),
  tpj = c(1,2,3)
)
```

I want to update the names of a few columns such that it looks like this:

```
d <- data.frame(
  sub = c(101, 102, 103),
  dmpfc_self = c(1,2,3),
  tpj_self = c(1,2,3)
)
```

Essentially, I'm appending the string '_self' to every column except sub.

I can manually relabel the columns, but is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ifelse`:

```
colnames(d) <- ifelse(colnames(d) != "sub", paste0(colnames(d), "_self"), colnames(d))
```

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

d %>% 
  rename_at(vars(-sub), .funs = ~paste0(., "_self"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dplyr::rename_with(d, ~paste0(.x, "_self"), -sub)
```

Result

```
  sub dmpfc_self tpj_self
1 101          1        1
2 102          2        2
3 103          3        3
```